# Error writing to input e.target.value in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

There is an array of inputs in two forms: 1. Empty when created. 2. With the created values from the server after creation and saving. My code for adding a value for each of the inputs in the array doesn't work in the second case and I don't understand what could be wrong. In the first case, the values are written normally, and in the second, nothing happens.

```
<input
  defaultValue={sectionValue[i].text}
  value={sectionValue[i].text}
  onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    sectionValue[i].text = e.target.value;
    setSectionValue([...sectionValue]);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. Any time you're changing state based on existing state, you're best off using the callback form of your state setter, because it's really easy for the handler to close over a stale copy of the state (`sectionValue` in your case).
2. You're breaking one of the rules of state: [don't directly modify state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). You're directly modifying the `sectionValue[i]` object. So it's the same object, but with a different `text` property. Later you're copying the *array*, but you need to copy the object as well. Sometimes it'll happen to render correctly when you do this, but other times — often — it won't.

To fix both, change:

```
sectionValue[i].text = e.target.value;
setSectionValue([...sectionValue]);
```

to

```
setSectionValue(oldSectionValue => {
    const newSectionValue = [...oldSectionValue];
    newSectionValue[i] = {
        ...oldSectionValue[i],
        text: e.target.value
    };
    return newSectionValue;
});
```

There's more than one way to do that, but the basic things are: 1. Use the callback, and 2. Copy both the object and the array.

---

Side note: Since `sectionValue` is an array, I'd suggest using the plural for it (`sectionValues`).